# Retrieve an Akka actor or create it if it does not exist

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I am developing an application that creates some Akka actors to manage and process messages coming from a Kafka topic. Messages with the same key are processed by the same actor. I use the message key also to name the corresponding actor.

When a new message is read from the topic, I don't know if the actor with the id equal to the message key was already created by the *actor system* or not. Therefore, I try to resolve the actor using its name, and if it does not exist yet, I create it. I need to manage concurrency in regard to actor resolution. So it is possible that more than one client asks the *actor system* if an actor exists.

The code I am using right now is the following:

```
private CompletableFuture<ActorRef> getActor(String uuid) {
    return system.actorSelection(String.format("/user/%s", uuid))
                 .resolveOne(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                 .toCompletableFuture()
                 .exceptionally(ex -> 
                     system.actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class, uuid), uuid))
                 .exceptionally(ex -> {
                     try {
                         return system.actorSelection(String.format("/user/%s",uuid)).resolveOne(Duration.ofMillis(1000)).toCompletableFuture().get();
                     } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                         throw new RuntimeException(e);
                     }
                 });
}
```

The above code is not optimised, and the exception handling can be made better.

However, is there in Akka a more idiomatic way to resolve an actor, or to create it if it does not exist? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider creating an actor that maintains as its state a map of message IDs to `ActorRef`s. This "receptionist" actor would handle all requests to obtain a message processing actor. When the receptionist receives a request for an actor (the request would include the message ID), it tries to look up an associated actor in its map: if such an actor is found, it returns the `ActorRef` to the sender; otherwise it creates a new processing actor, adds that actor to its map, and returns that actor reference to the sender.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It could be a good idea. However, I am talking about millions of actors :( I know, it should be inserted into the question...

Comment: In that case, look at Akka Clustering. It effectively does the same thing, but the actors are sharded across multiple partitions by some strategy you define. Messages use the partition strategy to route to a particular partition, then the partition directs them to the correct actor. If the actor isn't present, it's created. This will also let you scale out across multiple nodes if your millions of actors need it.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using `akka-cluster` and `akka-cluster-sharding`. First, this gives you *throughput*, and as well, reliability. However, it will also make the system manage the creation of the 'entity' actors.

But you have to change the way you talk to those actors. You create a `ShardRegion` actor which handles all the messages:

```java
import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.cluster.sharding.ClusterSharding;
import akka.cluster.sharding.ClusterShardingSettings;
import akka.cluster.sharding.ShardRegion;
import akka.event.Logging;
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter;


public class MyEventReceiver extends AbstractActor {

    private final ActorRef shardRegion;

    public static Props props() {
        return Props.create(MyEventReceiver.class, MyEventReceiver::new);
    }

    static ShardRegion.MessageExtractor messageExtractor 
      = new ShardRegion.HashCodeMessageExtractor(100) {
            // using the supplied hash code extractor to shard
            // the actors based on the hashcode of the entityid

        @Override
        public String entityId(Object message) {
            if (message instanceof EventInput) {
                return ((EventInput) message).uuid().toString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object entityMessage(Object message) {
            if (message instanceof EventInput) {
                return message;
            }
            return message; // I don't know why they do this it's in the sample
        }
    };


    public MyEventReceiver() {
        ActorSystem system = getContext().getSystem();
        ClusterShardingSettings settings =
           ClusterShardingSettings.create(system);
        // this is setup for the money shot
        shardRegion = ClusterSharding.get(system)
                .start("EventShardingSytem",
                        Props.create(EventActor.class),
                        settings,
                        messageExtractor);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder().match(
                EventInput.class,
                e -> {
                    log.info("Got an event with UUID {} forwarding ... ",
                            e.uuid());
                    // the money shot
                    deviceRegion.tell(e, getSender());
                }
        ).build();
    }
}
```

So this Actor `MyEventReceiver` runs on all nodes of your cluster, and encapsulates the `shardRegion` Actor. You no longer message your `EventActor`s directly, but, using the `MyEventReceiver` and `deviceRegion` Actors, you use the sharding system keep track of which node in the cluster the *particular* `EventActor` lives on. It will create one if none have been created before, or route it messages if it has. Every `EventActor` must have a unique id: which is extracted from the *message* (so a `UUID` is pretty good for that, but it could be some other id, like a customerID, or an orderID, or whatever, as long as its unique for the Actor instance you want to process it with).

(I'm omitting the `EventActor` code, it's otherwise a pretty normal Actor, depending what you are doing with it, the 'magic' is in the code above).

The sharding system automatically knows to create the `EventActor` and allocate it to a shard, based on the algorithm you've chosen (in this particular case, it's based on the `hashCode` of the unique ID, which is all I've ever used). Furthermore, you're *guaranteed* only *one* Actor for any given unique ID. The message is transparently routed to the correct Node and Shard wherever it is; from whichever Node and Shard it's being sent.

There's more info and sample code in the Akka site & documentation.

This is a pretty rad way to make sure that the same Entity/Actor always processes messages meant for it. The cluster and sharding takes automatic care of distributing the Actors properly, and failover and the like (you would have to add `akka-persistence` to get passivation, rehydration, and failover if the Actor has a bunch of strict state associated with it (that must be restored)).

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Jeffrey Chung is indeed of Akka way. The downside of such approach is its low performance. The most performant solution is to use Java's   [ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method.